# How can I sort these sentences

Tags: android

Can I sort these sentences depending on the word only like reality, seed, eventually, etc... using ArrayList or anything can do that?

```
01. reality ~ [ rēˈalətē ] ≠ [ unreality ]
- TV is used as an escape from reality.

02. seed ~ [ sēd ] ≠ [  ]
- A packet of sunflower seeds.

03. eventually ~ [ iˈvenCHo͞oəlē ] ≠ [  ]
- He eventually escaped and made his way back to England.
```

The output should be :

```
03. eventually ~ [ iˈvenCHo͞oəlē ] ≠ [  ]
- He eventually escaped and made his way back to England.

01. reality ~ [ rēˈalətē ] ≠ [ unreality ]
- TV is used as an escape from reality.

02. seed ~ [ sēd ] ≠ [  ]
- A packet of sunflower seeds.
```

Comment: What is the thing which needs to be sorted. How are word used to sort the sentences. Please give a much clear explanation of reaching output from input.

Comment: Please post your code so we know what kind of data you want sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider representing your entries as object and then sorting these objects.

Your entries may be represented as the following class:

```java
class Entry {
  private int index;
  private String word;
  private String pronunciation;
  @Nullable private String antonym;
  private String exampleSentence;

  // Constructor, getters omitted for brevity.

  @Override public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder()
      .append(index)
      .append(". ")
      .append(word)
      // build the rest of the entry as you posted above
      .toString()
  }
}
```

Now, in order to sort the objects of this class, you need add a way to compare them. There are 2 approaches.

You may make this implement the `Comparable` interface. This way is recommended, if your class has some kind of natural ordering. For example `Integer` implements this interface, as numbers has natural ascending order.

To implement `Comparable` and order the objects of your class by the word, you would modify the above definition as follows:

```java
class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
   // ...
   @Override 
   public int compareTo(Entry other) {
     return word.compareTo(other.word);
   }
}
```

We added a new method, `compareTo`. This method returns and int. When comparing this with other, it returns a negative value, zero, or positive value, when this < other, this = other and this > other respectively.

`String` in Java are naturally ordered by their lexicographical order, and therefore implement `Comparable`. Therefore we just delegate to the implementation of the field `word`.

Another way to compare objects is by implementing a `Comparator`. This way if preferred if your class has multiple or alternative ways of comparing its objects, which you'd like to expose.

You may implement a `Comparator` as follows:

```java
class EntryComparator implements Comparator<Entry> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Entry first, Entry second) {
    return first.getWord().compareTo(second.getWord);
  }
}
```

Again you override a single method, `compare`. This method also returns int - a negative value, zero, and a positive value means that first < second, first = second and first > second respectively.

Finally you want to sort your objects. You may use `Collections::sort` for this purpose:

```java
Collections.sort(entries); // if Entry is Comparable
Collections.sort(entries, new EntryComparator()); // if you defined a Comparator
```